# Navigation drawer bug when button onpressed

Tags: java, android, navigation, drawer

i am beginner here!

I am having a problem with my Navigation Drawer.

When i click on any button, next time, the button is invisible

Video:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PCGwofa6NPHh3P5Hqwuut1tG0qphEfUi

This is using Navigation View on android.

```
public class ActionBar {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    //private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    public ActionBar(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        //drawerLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        configureToolbar();
        configureNavigationDrawer();

    }

    private void configureToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionbar != null) {
            actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setTitle("");
        }

        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.cast).setOnClickListener(new Cast());


    }

    private void configureNavigationDrawer() {
        drawerLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navView = activity.findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_radio:
                    //CODE
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_recordings:
                    //CODE

                case R.id.nav_settings:

                    //CODE

                    break;

                case R.id.nav_share:
                    //CODE
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_about:

                    //CODE

                    break;

                case R.id.nav_feedback:

                    //CODE

                    break;

                case R.id.nav_exit:
                    activity.finish();
                    break;
            }
            activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        });

        navView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.drawable.navigation_drawer_item_color);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.empty_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private class Cast implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.not_yet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed" />
        <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
        <!--<item android:drawable="@color/pressed" />-->

</selector>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <!--<include layout="@layout/logo"/>-->
    <!--<include layout="@layout/bottom_controls"/>-->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
            <!-- For fragments -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <include layout="@layout/logo"/>
                <include layout="@layout/bottom_controls" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_items">


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The clicked button should not disappear

Comment: Your selector file doesn't seem correct. Instead of `android:drawable` you should use `android:color`. Or you should generate separate drawables for different states and use them in your selector file.